# translate data frame of observations into ranks

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set like this:

```
df <- data.frame(situation1=rnorm(30),
             situation2=rnorm(30),
             situation3=rnorm(30),
             models=c(rep("A",10), rep("B",10), rep("C", 10)))
```

where I compare three models (A,B,C) in three situations. I have 10 measurements for each model.

I now want to summarise this into ranks, i.e. how often each models wins in each situtation. Win is defined by the highest value.

A final output could be something like this:

```
model situation1 situtation2 situtation3
A          4          3            3
B          7          1            2
C          1          4            5
```

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when creating data frames using functions such as `rnorm`

Comment: sorry, added the definition for win. Win is the highest value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `base R`:

```
table(df$models,colnames(df[-4])[max.col(df[-4])])
#    situation1 situation2 situation3
#  A          2          4          4
#  B          4          5          1
#  C          2          4          4
```

Results may change from your OP, since you didn't set a `seed`.

Comment: nice solution, is there also an equivalent for the minimum?

Comment: Sure. `max.col(-df[-4])` will find the index of the minimum value of `df`.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this situtation wise. That means, how many wins has each model in e.g. situtation1. The final output should be the same as above but now the column sum will the 10 (not the row sum).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dplyr option:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(models) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(. == pmax(situation1, situation2, situation3))) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Or possibly a little more efficient:

```
df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-models), funs(. == pmax(situation1, situation2, situation3))) %>% 
  group_by(models) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum)
## A tibble: 3 × 4
#  models situation1 situation2 situation3
#   <chr>      <int>      <int>      <int>
#1      A          3          3          3
#2      B          3          5          1
#3      C          6          1          2
```

If you're looking for the minimum, use `pmin` instead of `pmax`. And in case there may be NAs, use the `na.rm`-argument in `pmax`/`pmin`.

Final note: the result doesn't match OP's because the sample data was generated without setting a seed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(Map(`==`, .SD, list(do.call(pmax, .SD))), sum), models]
```